# Processing files from URL

Tags: java, file, url

i have to fectch 500 txt files hosted here: https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B_R7SeoAotsmUUtYendIX04zRjA&usp=sharing  so i can index them and make a "search engine" the thing is i dont know how to get those files, i read how to read a specific file from a URL but i cant find what i need. I saw something about google drive sdk but i was wondering if is there another way Thanks in advance!!

PD: im working with java.

Comment: I think that Google tried really hard to prevent you from doing what you want
So you will probably will have to use the SDK

Comment: Try this link:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20665881/direct-download-from-google-drive-using-google-drive-api

It explains how to do what you want