# How can i upload image files to aws ec2 instance?

Tags: image, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, upload

My web application server on AWS ec2 instance.

And using MEAN stack.

I'd like to upload image to ec2 instance.(ex - /usr/local/web/images)

I can't found that how can i get the credentials.

There are just about AWS S3.

How can i upload image file to ec2 instance?

Comment: Use 'ssh' or 'scp' to upload the files to ec2 and the for that you'll have the key pair that you've got while creating instance.    I didn't understand 'There are just about aws s3' mean in the context.

Comment: @moderators why is this question downvoted ? User wasn't able to ask question properly, we should help him, instead of downvoting.

Answer (score 0):

If you do file transfer repeatedly try, [unison](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/). It is bidirectional, kind of sync. Allows options to handle conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the easiest way to do this as a one-off is to upload the file to google drive, and then download the file from there. View [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25010369/wget-curl-large-file-from-google-drive) thread to see how simply this can be done!

Answer (score 0):

clone from share git repo to EC2 and check the image path to display on website