# Download a Google Drive folder/file by using wget - Result: 404 not found

Tags: ubuntu, download, wget

I'm looking for a way to download files/folders from google drive by using wget. So far I found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37453841/download-a-file-from-google-drive-using-wget), but it doesn't work (404 not found). This is the link to a google docs file:

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1o-HNT5K08x7EzYZ3a-RzBWZvKrV_pY5CWUFlxJj6Lug/edit?usp=sharing

and I run the command:

```
wget "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1o-HNT5K08x7EzYZ3a-RzBWZvKrV_pY5CWUFlxJj6Lug"
```

The result is:

[image]