# How to download Python script from Google Drive to Google Colab, and avoid error "<!DOCTYPE html>" after importing script into Colab

Tags: python, download, google-drive-api, google-colaboratory

I Uploaded a python script into my Google Drive, and download it into Google Colab by:

```
!wget "https://drive.google.com/[URL]" -O "script.py"
```

After downloading, when I import function from script in a cell in Google Colab:

```
from script.py import my_fun
```

I get the error:

```
File "/content/script.py", line 2
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

When I check the content of "script.py", it is similar to a HTML file not python script. Is there anyway to download python script to Google Colab?

Is there any chance that the Google Drive URL that I use is wrong?

How I get URL in Google Drive:

- Right click on the script file in Google Drive
- Select "Get Link"
- I select my company group and select "viewer" permission.
- Click "Copy Link"

Thank you for reading my question.

Comment: That's not an error, it's just a feature of how Google Drive serves content. Probably find a less crazy way to host your scripts; GitHub allows you to serve up things raw, without HTML headers.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem might be related to the use itself of wget. https://stackoverflow.com/a/39087286/12664376 This answer to the question [download-a-file-from-google-drive-using-wget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37453841/download-a-file-from-google-drive-using-wget) might help you. Note that some people say it doesn't work anymore, so see some acomments on that answer, or this other answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/58821707/12664376.

Comment: Thank you. The method explained in the above link didn't work for me. I found a python library named "gdown" which works.

Comment: @Mohammad thanks for the info, maybe I'll use it someday in the future