# R How to read a file from google drive using R

Tags: r, url, dataset

I would like to read in R a dataset from google drive as the
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EgnzB.png) indicated.

Neither

```
url <- "https://drive.google.com/file/d/1AiZda_1-2nwrxI8fLD0Y6e5rTg7aocv0"
temp <- tempfile()
download.file(url, temp)
bank <- read.table(unz(temp, "bank-additional.csv"))
unlink(temp)
```

nor

```
library(RCurl)
bank_url <- dowload.file(url, "bank-additional.csv", method = 'curl')
```

works.

I have been working on this for many hours. Any hints or solutions would be really appreciate.

Comment: How about using the `googledrive` library from the tidyverse? http://googledrive.tidyverse.org/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try

```
temp <- tempfile(fileext = ".zip")
download.file("https://drive.google.com/uc?authuser=0&id=1AiZda_1-2nwrxI8fLD0Y6e5rTg7aocv0&export=download",
  temp)
out <- unzip(temp, exdir = tempdir())
bank <- read.csv(out[14], sep = ";")
str(bank)
# 'data.frame': 4119 obs. of  21 variables:
 # $ age           : int  30 39 25 38 47 32 32 41 31 35 ...
 # $ job           : Factor w/ 12 levels "admin.","blue-collar",..: 2 8 8 8 1 8 1 3 8 2 ...
 # $ marital       : Factor w/ 4 levels "divorced","married",..: 2 3 2 2 2 3 3 2 1 2 ...
 # <snip>
```

The URL should correspond to the URL that you use to download the file using your browser.

As @Mako212 points out, you can also make use of the `googledrive` package, substituting `drive_download` for `download.file`:

```
library(googledrive)
temp <- tempfile(fileext = ".zip")
dl <- drive_download(
  as_id("1AiZda_1-2nwrxI8fLD0Y6e5rTg7aocv0"), path = temp, overwrite = TRUE)
out <- unzip(temp, exdir = tempdir())
bank <- read.csv(out[14], sep = ";")
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The second method works perfectly.  But for the first method, when I run out <- unzip(temp, exdir = tempdir()), I get warning messages " In unzip(temp, exdir = tempdir()) : internal error in 'unz' code "

Comment: googledrive will ask to authenticate with your google account so this answer will not work if you don't or can't authenticate.

Comment: When I try this I get a warning `error 1 in extracting from zip file` and `out=NULL`. Also the file that is downloaded is way too small to be right, which probably causes the problem. The link to google drive works outside of R though.

Comment: As commented by previous users -- this gives a warning for the download.file and cannot connect for googledrive option.

Answer (score 6):

- The google drive share link is not the direct file link, so `1. download.file` `2. RCurl` `first method in accepted answer` only download the web page showing the file, not file itself. You can edit the downloaded file and see it's a html file.
- You can find out the actual direct link to file with [this](https://sites.google.com/site/gdocs2direct/). With the direct link all the regular download methods will work.
- For very detailed discussions about getting the direct link or downloading it, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25010369/wget-curl-large-file-from-google-drive).
- Google drive api require client to sign in, so googledrive package also ask you to sign in google if not already signed in.

Answer (score 1):

You can do all this with the [`googledrive` package](https://googledrive.tidyverse.org/).

It's a two-step process where you first find the folder in order to get it's ID, and then query for all files with that folder as the parents.

```
dir = drive_find(pattern='my_folder', type='folder')
query = paste('"', dir$id, '"',  ' in parents', sep='')
drive_find(q=query)
```

Note that `drive_find` may return multiple folders if you have multiple folders all named "my_folder" in different parts of Drive, so you may need to modify the query to be more specific (i.e. by searching by a parent folder). I would suggest throwing in a check that only one folder is returned by just doing `nrow(dir) == 1`. You can also change the query to use regex to indicate that it should only return an exact match on the folder name. In that case, replace the `drive_find` command with

```
drive_find(pattern='^my_folder$', type='folder')
```

You can find more details on parameters for `drive_find` at [the documentation](https://googledrive.tidyverse.org/reference/drive_find.html).