# Download .rds from google drive using download.file()

Tags: download, amazon-rds, drive, tempdir

I am still having trouble getting a large file (.rds) from google drive into R. The purpose is to pull the rds file from drive, for use in an Rshiny.app.

If I use

```
library(googledrive)
temp <- tempfile(fileext = ".rds")
dl <- drive_download(
  as_id("XXXXXXXXX"), path = temp, overwrite = TRUE)
myObj<-readRDS(file = dl$local_path)
```

It works fine, because it downloads the file by ID into the tempdir. But then it requires token auth for tidyverse (almost) every time.

There are other options using `download.file()`  as in [R How to read a file from google drive using R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47851761/r-how-to-read-a-file-from-google-drive-using-r), however I am running into the issue that the share/download link leads to a prompt, notifying users of virus scan.

[Google Drive Download Warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4hKpZ.png)

I have tried direct download links, changing href, shareable link, with no success. Any ideas how I can work around this, using the share/download link and `download.file()`?

Comment: Did you manage to do this? I am in the same situation, I want to use google drive to put the big rds file and I want to use it for shinyapps. Or do you manage to find other working alternatives?