# Is there a way to access files in google drive from R?

Tags: r, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I have tried accessing a file using googlesheet4 and googledrive package but I just get an error. Funny enough I managed to access files the other day. I have provided authentication as needed. Any leads?

`googledrive::drive_get("chicken") %>%  read_sheet()`

`'cli_abort' is not an exported object from 'namespace:cli'`

Comment: check this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47851761/r-how-to-read-a-file-from-google-drive-using-r

Comment: Does this answer your question? [R How to read a file from google drive using R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47851761/r-how-to-read-a-file-from-google-drive-using-r)

Comment: Am at the tail end of downloading the file but it looks like it will take the whole day.  I have been able achieve 90% of the reading process

Comment: Could it because the file is html

`Rtmps5WtWZ/Summary.html` is the last bit of the file

Answer (score 0):

After many attempts, I realsied the drive_download would just suffice.

`googledrive::drive_download("chicken")`