# How to download a Google Drive url via curl or wget

Tags: curl, google-drive-api, wget

Is there a way to download a publicly-viewable Google Drive url via curl or wget? For example, being able to do something like:

```
curl -O myfile.xls https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1Wb2NfKTQr_dLoFJH0GfM0cx-t4r07IVl
```

Note, I'm looking to do this on a **publicly-viewable** file without having to sign into my Google account (or have someone else sign into their account, etc.).

If helpful, the cors headers I have are:

```
 "kind": "drive#file",
 "id": "1Wb2NfKTQr_dLoFJH0GfM0cx-t4r07IVl",
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [wget/curl large file from google drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25010369/wget-curl-large-file-from-google-drive)

Answer (score 119, accepted):

How about this method? When the file is such large size, Google returns a code for downloading the file. You can download the file using the code. When such large file is downloaded using curl, you can see the code as follows.

```
<a id="uc-download-link" class="goog-inline-block jfk-button jfk-button-action" href="/uc?export=download&amp;confirm=ABCD&amp;id=### file ID ###">download</a>
```

The query with `confirm=ABCD` is important for downloading the file. This code is also included in the cookie. At the cookie, you can see it as follows.

```
#HttpOnly_.drive.google.com TRUE    /uc TRUE    #####   download_warning_#####  ABCD
```

In this case, "ABCD" is the code. In order to retrieve the code from the cookie and download the file, you can use the following script.

### Sample script :

```
#!/bin/bash
fileid="### file id ###"
filename="MyFile.csv"
curl -c ./cookie -s -L "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=${fileid}" > /dev/null
curl -Lb ./cookie "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&confirm=`awk '/download/ {print $NF}' ./cookie`&id=${fileid}" -o ${filename}
```

If this was not useful for you, I'm sorry.

---

### Updated at February 17, 2022

Recently, it seems that the specification of this flow has been changed. So I updated this answer. **In order to download a publicly shared file of large size from Google Drive, you can use the following script.**

```
#!/bin/bash
fileid="### file id ###"
filename="MyFile.csv"
html=`curl -c ./cookie -s -L "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=${fileid}"`
curl -Lb ./cookie "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&`echo ${html}|grep -Po '(confirm=[a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+)'`&id=${fileid}" -o ${filename}
```

- In this case, the ID for downloading is retrieved from the HTML data as follows.

  ```
  <form id="downloadForm" action="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&amp;id={fileId}&amp;confirm={value for downloading}" method="post">
  ```
- **When you want to download a publicly shared file of small size from Google Drive, you can use the following command.**

  ```
  curl -L "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=### fileId ###" -o sampleoutput.csv
  ```

### Updated at January 21, 2024

From [the following @excellproj 's comment](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/f0f2d122e05bf5f971611258c22c110f?permalink_comment_id=4841458#gistcomment-4841458),

> January 2024
> curl -L "https://drive.usercontent.google.com/download?id=${fileId}&export=download&confirm=t" -o "file.zip"
> working great for me. Small and large files

I checked this endpoint. By this, the following result is obtained. In the current stage, the following endpoint can be used.

```
https://drive.usercontent.google.com/download?id={fileId}&confirm=xxx
```

It seems that in the current stage, various values can be used to `xxx` of `confirm=xxx`. So, even `confirm=xxx` and `confirm=yy` and `confirm=z` can be used.

The sample curl command is as follows.

```bash
curl "https://drive.usercontent.google.com/download?id={fileId}&confirm=xxx" -o filename
```

And/or,

```bash
curl -L "https://drive.usercontent.google.com/download?id={fileId}&confirm=xxx" -o filename
```

Comment: this is the only solution that works without installing anything, thanks

Comment: Hi Tanaike, sometimes the cookie file will not contain the cookie with `.drive.google.com`. This would happen occasionally, I tried wget but still got a similar cookie file. Do you know why this could happen?

Comment: @shooding Thank you for your comment and for testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.

Comment: These commands download the virus scan warning html page for me.

Comment: @Steve Thank you for your comment. About `These commands download the virus scan warning html page for me.`, I'm worried that the specification might be changed at Google side. So, when I tested the method of "Updated at February 17, 2022", I confirmed that both large-size and small-size files could be correctly downloaded. From this result, it seems that the specification is not changed. Unfortunately, I cannot replicate your situation. I apologize for this. But I would like to support you. When I could correctly replicate your situation, I would like to think of a solution.

Comment: Try this:  `$ curl -L -o myfile.zip "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=xxxxxx&confirm=yes"` No tools, no installation, no multiline chain of commands. It worked for me for larger files(200MB+) out of the box.

Answer (score 37):

**Simplest and best way (with a real Google Drive file example)**

1. Install [gdown](https://pypi.org/project/gdown/) using `pip`

   - Command - `pip install gdown`
2. Let's say I wish to download [cnn_stories.tgz](https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0BwmD_VLjROrfTHk4NFg2SndKcjQ) from Google Drive

   - Download Link: `https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0BwmD_VLjROrfTHk4NFg2SndKcjQ`
3. Please note the `id` URL parameter `0BwmD_VLjROrfTHk4NFg2SndKcjQ` in the link
4. That's it! Download the file using `gdown`

   - `gdown --id 0BwmD_VLjROrfTHk4NFg2SndKcjQ --output cnn_stories.tgz`

**TLDR:** `gdown --id {gdrive_file_id} --output {file_name}`

---

Command Line Args:

`--id : Google drive file ID`

`--output: Output File name`

Comment: i mostly use wget but at the current moment (2024) i am no longer able to do it. and this one is works, thanks

Answer (score 23):

You need to use the `-L` switch to make curl follow redirects, and the correct switch for the filename is `-o`. You should also quote the URL:

```
 curl -L -o myfile.xls "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0B4fk8L6brI_eX1U5Ui1Lb1FpVG8"
```

Comment: thanks, that works on small files. However, if the file is larger, using the above code I get something that says `"MyFile.csv (711M) is too large for Google to scan for viruses. Would you still like to download this file?`. How would I download a file of any size then?

Comment: You wouldn't be able to do that with curl or wget alone. You would need a program to recognise that page and submit a "Yes" response.

Comment: For larger files, try this:  `$ curl -L -o myfile.zip "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=xxxxxx&confirm=yes"`. It worked for me for larger files(200MB+) out of the box.

Answer (score 14):

Simply

```
wget --no-check-certificate -r 'https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&id=FILEID' -O DESTINEATION_FILENAME
```

[source](https://gist.github.com/iamtekeste/3cdfd0366ebfd2c0d805)

Comment: although it downloads the large file fine. But somehow it corrupted the file, by merging few files into one?

Answer (score 11):

No need to install any external tool.

1. Make file public on google drive
2. Open shared link in incognito mode
3. Click on download button
4. Copy as curl download request from network tab
5. Paste copied request on server & append output(`--output <FILENAME>`) flag

[image: Step 4]
[image: Step 5]

Comment: Minor correction, after you copy the cURL command, you have to append the following flag in curl '--output filename.ext'

Comment: i have highlighted it in image `--output file.zip`, Also check the 5th step

Answer (score 6):

I've just checked the answer of @tanaike and it works like a charm. But the solution, proposed by @Martin Broadhurst and accepted by the topicstarter doesn't.

Because google shows the warning about virus scan, which needs to be processed, soc script required.

I'd like to vote for the @tanaike's answer, but don't have enough reputation to do this :)

Additionally for those, who don't know how to get and ID of a file on google drive I'd like to share this pretty simple knowledge.

1. [go to your gDrive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BlEZI.png)
2. [right click on it and select "Share option"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ywyIh.png)
3. [choose public share for all, who have a link with no login required](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3jGZG.png)
4. copy the URL
   https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FNUZiDDDDDDSSSSSSAAAAAdv42Qgzb6n8d/view?usp=sharing
5. paste it to some notepad
6. ID is a part of URL: 
   **1FNUZiDDDDDDSSSSSSAAAAAdv42Qgzb6n8d**

Enjoy!

Comment: Thank you for your comment. In order to more easily download shared files, I created this. If this is useful for you, I'm glad. https://github.com/tanaikech/goodls

Comment: Not able to install it, probably because of some the same ignorance that makes me trying to install it...

Answer (score 6):

As of **18 Nov 2019** to use wget to download a file from Google Drive, I used the following method. For this method, we need to know, whether our file size comes under small or large cat. I could not figure out the exact number which differentiate between small and large sizes, but I suppose it is some where around 100 MB. But you can always use any of the two methods mentioned for your files, as one will only work for small and other for large.

**Basic Steps to be followed**

*Step 1* Make your file to be shared as "Accessible to anyone having internet". This can be done by Right Clicking the file --> Click on Share option --> Click on Advances radio button --> Change access to "Public On the web"

*Step 2* Save it and click Done
*Step 3* Again right click on the file and click on "Get Shareable Link". This will copy the link to clipboard.

*Step 4* Copy everything after **?id=** till end and save it to notepad file. This is your FILE_ID, which is used below.

*Step 4* Follow below mentioned steps, based on file sizes, after performing above common steps.

**Small Files**

*Step 1* Use the command:

```
wget --no-check-certificate 'https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&id=FILE_ID' -O FILE_NAME_ALONG_WITH_SUFFIX
```

FILE_ID should be copied from above step and FILE_NAME_ALONG_WITH_SUFFIX is the name of the file you want it to save it on your system/ server. Note that, do not forget to add the suffix like (.zip , .txt etc)

*Step 2* Run the command. It may show "Will not apply HSTS" as error but its ok. Your file will be copied.

**Large Files**

*Step 1* Use the command

```
wget --no-check-certificate --load-cookies /tmp/cookies.txt "https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&confirm=$(wget --quiet --save-cookies /tmp/cookies.txt --keep-session-cookies --no-check-certificate 'https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&id=FILE_ID' -O- | sed -rn 's/.*confirm=([0-9A-Za-z_]+).*/\1\n/p')&id=FILE_ID" -O FILE_NAME_ALONG_WITH_SUFFIX && rm -rf /tmp/cookies.txt
```

Change FILE_ID in 2 locations and FILE_NAME_WITH_SUFFIX once.

*Step 2* Execute the command, it may give same error as mentioned above but thats ok.

Hope it helps..

Answer (score 2):

## For small file

Run following command on your terminal:

```
wget --no-check-certificate 'https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&id=FILEID' -O FILENAME
```

In the above command change the **FILEID** by above id extracted and rename **FILENAME** for your own simple use.

---

## For large file

Run the following command with necessary changes in **FILEID** and **FILENAME**:

```
wget --load-cookies /tmp/cookies.txt "https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&confirm=$(wget --quiet --save-cookies /tmp/cookies.txt --keep-session-cookies --no-check-certificate 'https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&id=FILEID' -O- | sed -rn 's/.*confirm=([0-9A-Za-z_]+).*/\1\n/p')&id=FILEID" -O FILENAME && rm -rf /tmp/cookies.txt
```

---

You can also use [this](https://gdrive-wget.glitch.me/) single purpose website to generate this command for you.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a tool called [**gdrive**](https://github.com/prasmussen/gdrive) instead of wget/curl. It is basically a tool to access a google drive account from the command-line. Follow this example to set it up for a Linux machine:

1. At first download the execution file of gdrive [here](https://github.com/prasmussen/gdrive/releases).
2. Decompress it and get the executable file `gdrive`. Now change the permissions of the file by executing the command
   `chmod +x gdrive`.
3. Run `./gdrive about` and you will get a URL asking you to enter for a verification code.
   As instructed in the prompt copy the link and go to the URL on your **browser**, then log into your Google Drive account and grant permission. You will get some verification code at last. Copy it.
4. Go back to your previous terminal and paste the verification code you just copied. Then verify
   your information there.

Now once successfully completed the authentication process above you can navigate the files on your drive using the commands mentioned below.

```
./gdrive list # List all files' information in your account
./gdrive list -q "name contains 'University'" # serch files by name
./gdrive download fileID # Download some file. You can find the fileID from the 'gdrive list' result.
./gdrive upload filename  #  Upload a local file to your google drive account.
./gdrive mkdir # Create new folder
```

The process has to be done only once and it works seamlessly.

Answer (score 2):

This solution works even for large files, without cookies.

The trick is the **&confirm=yes** query param. Then:

```
wget "drive.google.com/u/3/uc?id=FILEID&export=download&confirm=yes"
```

Comment: This simple and useful answer should get way more recognition. 
It works for me for larger files(200MB+) out of the box. 
I tried this

                ```$ curl -L -o myfile.zip "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=xxxxxx&confirm=yes"```                 
No tools, no installation, no multiline chain of commands.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the best way to do it in CURL step by step:

Windows 10 have CURL by default but below applies to any Machines.

First generate a Direct Link of your file. A simple tool like [this](https://sites.google.com/site/gdocs2direct/) will help, I have listed some of what I used [here](https://share.link/fugata-scans-scanlation/b645) in case the one here will go down someday.

Or just replace the XXX's below to your file ID.

```
https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

Note: Drive file should be available to anyone with the link. instructions are [here](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/7166529?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en#zippy=%2Canyone-with-a-link-to-the-folder).

Now open a new tab and paste the new generated links and that will automatically download the file.

However if it shows the infamous "scanning for virus / cannot scan for virus " page then we cannot use it yet with CURL.

You have to create a google drive API and use the below link structure instead:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/XXXXXXXXX?alt=media&key=YYYYYYYYY
```

XXXXX's is your file ID and YYYYY's is the API KEY (currently Version 3). Alternatively you can use this [generator](https://www.wonderplugin.com/online-tools/google-drive-direct-link-generator/) tool as an aid.

But again you need API first so head over [HERE](https://bytesbin.com/skip-google-drive-virus-scan-warning-large-files/) for instructions on how to.

Now that the direct link is ready, the most important thing to do is make sure that you have a [USER AGENT](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent) set in your CURL command because without is you will received an error saying that you reach the limits. Here's the final command:

```
curl -A "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64)" -L "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX?alt=media&key=YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY" -o filename.zip
```

The above is set to the [Latest Chrome on Windows User Agents](https://www.whatismybrowser.com/guides/the-latest-user-agent/chrome) but should work on any machines regardless. It only mimics the browser thinking it's Chrome for Windows 10 and latest. refer [here](https://www.whatismybrowser.com/guides/the-latest-user-agent/chrome) for a the latest one as using an OLD UA is also throwing an error.

If you find it helpfull please let me know,

Answer (score 0):

For wget to work successfully for large files, use the link that asks confirmation to download.

First get the info from that google drive link that has ID. In your case the ID is `1Wb2NfKTQr_dLoFJH0GfM0cx-t4r07IVl`.

And then get the file name that you want to download.

Then use this:

````
wget --load-cookies /tmp/cookies.txt "https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&confirm=$(wget --quiet --save-cookies /tmp/cookies.txt --keep-session-cookies --no-check-certificate 'https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&id=FILEID' -O- | sed -rn 's/.*confirm=([0-9A-Za-z_]+).*/\1\n/p')&id=FILEID" -O FILENAME && rm -rf /tmp/cookies.txt```

and replace the FILEID with the ID that you get from the link and the FILENAME variable with your file name

For any reference see this thread patiently https://gist.github.com/iamtekeste/3cdfd0366ebfd2c0d805 . You can get many useful methods.
````

Answer (score 0):

As of **2024**, Google will block most downloads after it even smells `curl`'s user agent. (Google behaviour might change by country. it might be more lenient, for now, for your privileged location). Instead you will get this "Denied" screen if you try most of the "copy links" answers above:

[image: Google drive denied access for 24h]
(The message is known to be a lie because I created the shared file link, and I was the only one trying to download it exactly once using curl)

The only "reliable" option i have found is to use [rclone](https://rclone.org/drive/#service-account-support). And then it also requires *a lot* of work on Google interfaces.

- You must have or create a google account.
- You must create a Service Account in your google account.
- You must create an API access token for your new service account.
- You must configure
  rclone to use the api token.

After that, every google drive link is only two steps:

1. Add file to your account
2. execute `rclone copy mygdrive:/filename.txt dest_dir`

Answer (score 0):

**January 2024**

```
curl -L "https://drive.usercontent.google.com/download?id=${xxxxxxxx}&export=download&confirm=y" -o "file.zip"
```

working great for me. Small and large files

**P.S.**
Other link formats provided in the responses below don't work for me, so I'm posting this variant. Perhaps someone will find it useful.