# Wget get past "infected with a virus" screen on Google Drive

Tags: google-drive-api, wget

So I've been trying to get wget to download a Google Drive file that I uploaded. Unfortunately, Google Drive incorrectly flags the file as a virus, so wget can't get the direct download link.

Things I've tried:

- using the `gdrive.pl` fie that someone made, but I'm on Windows, and `/tmp/cookies.txt` does not exist.
- doing `wget --no-check-certificate https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&id=FILEID -O FILENAME`, but it says `400 Bad Request`
- using `https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&id=ID`, but it fails because of the `download infected file` warning.

Does anyone have any suggestions to solve this?

Comment: According to the [rest api](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/get) you could use the parameter `acknowledgeAbuse=true`.

Comment: Is the file shared?

Comment: Yes. It is shared and I have the ID and the public link

Comment: Although this is not a sample for wget, is this information useful for you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48133080/how-to-download-a-google-drive-url-via-curl-or-wget/48133859#48133859

Comment: The bad request part may be from "&" being parsed in the command, you may need to wrap the url in quotes.

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I was able to do, based on a starting point I found at https://medium.com/@acpanjan/download-google-drive-files-using-wget-3c2c025a8b99 :

**Edit** *I noticed you said Windows, so this command with sed won't work natively in Windows - I'll put steps without sed for Windows below*

You of course start by sharing the file and getting the file ID from the share link on google drive. Then:

```
wget --save-cookies /tmp/cookies.txt --keep-session-cookies --no-check-certificate "https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&id=SHARE_LINK_ID" -O- | sed -rn 's/.*confirm=([0-9A-Za-z_]+).*/\1\n/p' > /tmp/confirm && wget --load-cookies /tmp/cookies.txt --no-check-certificate "https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&confirm="$(cat /tmp/confirm)"&id=SHARE_LINK_ID" -O YOUR_FILENAME && rm /tmp/cookies.txt /tmp/confirm
```

Replace SHARE_LINK_ID with your ID from your shared file link. Replace YOUR_FILENAME with your desired output file name.

This attempts to download the file and gets the html of the warning message about potential viruses in the file. It uses cookies as you need to use the same session ID for the subsequent download with the confirmation code.

It then gets the generated confirm code from that response and writes it to a temporary file.

I then does another wget adding the confirmation code to the query string to download the file, using the saved cookie to allow the confirmation code to work for the saved session.

Most likely this could be worked into a script, passing an argument of the share link ID to make it more useful.

**For Windows (without sed)**

```
 wget --save-cookies %TMP%/cookies.txt --keep-session-cookies --no-check-certificate "https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&id=SHARE_LINK_ID" -O %TMP%/confirm.txt
```

Downloads the confirmation html.

```
 notepad %TMP%/confirm.txt
```

Opens %TMP%/confirm.txt in Notepad to get the confirm code string (CTRL+F to look for "confirm=" and get the code right after that). Replace it in the below command line (along with putting in the filename you want and the share link ID from google drive)

```
 wget --load-cookies %TMP%/cookies.txt --no-check-certificate "https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&confirm=CONFIRM_CODE&id=SHARE_LINK_ID" -O YOUR_FILENAME
```

Delete the temp files:

```
 del %TMP%/cookies.txt %TMP%/confirm.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Don't forget to replace two FILEID and one FILENAME fields with your desired file's file id and the output file's name respectively.

> ```
> wget --load-cookies /tmp/cookies.txt "https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&confirm=$(wget --quiet --save-cookies /tmp/cookies.txt --keep-session-cookies --no-check-certificate 'https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&id=FILEID' -O- | sed -rn 's/.*confirm=([0-9A-Za-z_]+).*/\1\n/p')&id=FILEID" -O FILENAME && rm -rf /tmp/cookies.txt
> ```

<sub>source: https://medium.com/geekculture/wget-large-files-from-google-drive-336ba2e1c991</sub>