# How to find or pick a suitable Chrome/Chromium revision number?

Tags: puppeteer, puppeteer-sharp

I couldn't figure out a nice way to determine a suitable revision number to use with [Puppeteer Sharp](https://github.com/kblok/puppeteer-sharp).

What I did was use the version lookup feature on the "[OmahaProxy - Google Chrome](http://omahaproxy.appspot.com/)" site. I looked-up the version of Chrome I'm running on my computer. [That seems like a reasonable starting point.] I *assumed* (guessed) that the "Branch Base Position" shown in the version info was a revision number.

I then opened [the Chromium continuous builds archive](https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/chromium-browser-snapshots/index.html) and looked for a build for the revision *around* the revision number I found from the "OmahaProxy" site.

Is there a better way to find or pick a suitable revision number?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Puppeteer is always bundled with a specific revision of a specific version. I usually check [the release information on Github](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/releases) where the expected Chromium version and revision is specified. For example:

> ## [v1.17.0](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/releases/tag/v1.17.0)
>
> **Big Changes**
>
> - Chromium 76.0.3803.0 (r662092)

Then to download the right one,

1. Go to [Chromium browser snapshots](https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/chromium-browser-snapshots/index.html)
2. Choose the directory of your platform (e.g., `Linux_x64`)
3. Copy the revision number into the "**Filter:**" field without the "r" (e.g., `662092`)
4. Download the `.zip` file you need.

---

#### Additional info

1. The URL template below can be just plugged in with the right information:

   `https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/chromium-browser-snapshots/index.html?prefix=`**`<platform>`**`/`**`<revision>`**`/`

   For example:
   https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/chromium-browser-snapshots/index.html?prefix=Linux_x64/662092/
2. The most common issue on Linux is missing dependencies, and the [Puppeteer "Troubleshooting" document](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/troubleshooting.md) specifies all [the Linux dependencies](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/troubleshooting.md#chrome-headless-doesnt-launch-on-unix). (See [`apt` instructions for Ubuntu](https://medium.com/@cloverinks/how-to-fix-puppetteer-error-ibx11-xcb-so-1-on-ubuntu-152c336368).)
3. `curl` needs `-L` when downloading on the console. See [Stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48133080/how-to-download-a-google-drive-url-via-curl-or-wget/48133859).
4. When one is using `puppeteer-core`,

   > you will then need to call [`puppeteer.connect(\[options\])`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#puppeteerconnectoptions) or
   >   [`puppeteer.launch(\[options\])`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#puppeteerlaunchoptions) with an explicit `executablePath`
   >   option.

   (from [`puppeteer` vs `puppeteer-core`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#puppeteer-vs-puppeteer-core))

Answer (score 2):

Puppeteer requires number which correspond Chromium browser build snapshot number. You can get the latest snapshot number here:

- https://www.googleapis.com/download/storage/v1/b/chromium-browser-snapshots/o/Win_x64%2FLAST_CHANGE?generation=1528272852044880&alt=media

or you can view all available snapshots here:

- https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/chromium-browser-snapshots/index.html?prefix=Win_x64/

Comment: Thanks! What about finding an available snapshot for (or close too) a version number shown in the regular Google Chrome UI? How could I find something like 'the most recent stable version' of Chromium? (Maybe all released versions, not part of the 'beta' or 'canary' feeds, are considered 'stable'?)

Comment: I think the easiest way is just to use Downloader.DefaultRevision constant

Comment: I guess that'd work. The constant shouldn't change without my updating Puppeteer Sharp in my code. I'd prefer tho that it not update at all even then (to prevent unpleasant surprises).

Answer (score 1):

You can visit https://omahaproxy.appspot.com/deps.json?version=71.0.3542.0  。This chromium_ base_ Position should be what you want。This API comes from https://omahaproxy.appspot.com/

Comment: The link in this answer is to an API endpoint that provides the information the OP is asking for — so the link is actually the only generalized solution to OP’s question.