# How to download drive files through HTTP requests with the access_token included in the url?

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api, google-oauth, http-live-streaming

Can someone please help me on finding a way to send an HTTP request to Google Drive to download a file with the access token included in the url?

I searched a lot in the internet and found only this way to send an access_token in URL:
"https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/[fileID]?access_token=ya29.a0AfH6SMA4FU********&key=[apiKey]"

As you know, it only returns the metadata of the file because it does not contain alt=media. If you add "alt=meida" to the url, it fails to load and returns nothing.

It can be easily fixed with passing the access_token as a header. However, I cannot do that because I am using the url as a "src" of HTML  and as a source for video segments in .m3u8 file.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Is the resource public or private?

Comment: I tried it with both public and private but all failed

Comment: In this case there is an already accepted answer for public files here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48133859/7453656 . For private files it's impossible without using OAuth2.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to download a Google Drive url via curl or wget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48133080/how-to-download-a-google-drive-url-via-curl-or-wget)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since January 1st, 2020, the Google Drive API doesn't support the `access_token` query parameter anymore.
See https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/application-development/upcoming-changes-to-the-google-drive-api-and-google-picker-api for the announcement.
This change only applies to requests with `?alt=media` by the way. Unfortunately that's precisely the kind of requests that you're using...
I'm afraid there's no solution in your case.

Comment: Thank you very much