# How to link Materialize.min.js from Google Drive to Google Apps Script

Tags: html, google-apps-script, google-drive-api, cdn

I got a number of Google Apps Script Web Apps. They all use image files, Materialize.min.css, and materilize.min.js sitting on other servers. I wanted to move all those files under my control onto my google drive. I've been successful with the image files and the materialize.min.css, but for some reason the `maerialize.min.js` is causing problems.

For the CSS files I used to use

```
link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css" /
```

I now use

```
link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1UQ_tm8_bUOXWj1GdzS8JmkehwVf5sW3A" />
```

And it all works well.

For the JS files: I used to use

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script> <?!= include("page-js");?>"
```

I've tried

```
<script src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1SkfRcC1jQwNLRVEUPgjQHSUkEFdg1BND"></script> <?!= include("page-js");?>"
```

Also tried `export=view`
I get the runtime error

> userCodeAppPanel:47 Uncaught ReferenceError: M is not defined at HTMLDocument.

So it seems to read the file, but doesn't seem to load the js????

I'm not sure how to fix it.
Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Update:

As noted by [chris](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13586390/chris) in this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69702204/how-to-link-materialize-min-js-from-google-drive-to-google-apps-script/69714598#comment123229867_69714598), you maybe able to simply change the file extension to a `txt` or a `css` file to bypass all security restrictions.

The URL should be of format:

```
https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=###fileId###
```

---

This is because  Google Drive recognizes that this is a `js` file and doesn't allow a direct link, but redirects to a warning page which requires a confirmation by the end user(using a query string `confirm=****` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48133859/)). Unfortunately, I don't think it's possible to retrieve this confirmation token client side due to [CORB](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/refs/heads/main/services/network/cross_origin_read_blocking_explainer.md#What-types-of-content-are-protected-by-CORB).

#### Workaround:

- Create a simple web app function [`doGet()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web#requirements_for_web_apps)
- Return data using [ContentService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/content)
- Use the published web app url in `script src`

Comment: Thanks so much.  Really helpful.  Your explanation gave me another idea.  I copied the file onto Win10..renamed it by changing file type to CSS ( as I know that type of file works) and uploaded back to drive. Linking to the renamed file and everything works. 
Thanks again.

Comment: @Chris Ha ha. Nice.

Comment: FYI. Moving links to Google drive improved performance. On average execution time  was 1.3 secs... Now down to 1.1 secs.