# get files data of folder gdrive without api

Tags: python, api, google-drive-api

So I have a problem I just want to get files link from a drive folder but I find out that can only done by API of google drive but I don't want to use API for that. I was thinking I can do that with simple web scrapping but I found out it can not happen because drive use server to get link.

In simple words I want to know how to get files data from folder of Google-drive without API.

Comment: About `In simple words I want to know how to get files data from folder of Google-drive without API.`, in this case, do you want to retrieve the data from who's Google Drive? Your Google Drive or other user's Google Drive?

Comment: anyone with a public link

Comment: Thank you for replying. From `anyone with a public link`, in this case, I thought that this flow might be able to be used. https://stackoverflow.com/a/48133859 How about checking the flow for downloading it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should consult the [Terms of service](https://policies.google.com/terms?hl=en-US) google does not allow web scraping.

You should use the Google drive api to do this.  If you want to get file data then this is the best way forward.

Google even has serval samples to help you get started [manage-downloads](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/manage-uploads)