# CORS Error and Format Not Supported with VideoJS and Google Drive Videos

Tags: google-drive-api, video.js, google-drive-shared-drive

I'm currently working on a project using Vue.js with VideoJS and trying to play videos hosted on Google Drive. However, I'm encountering a CORS error and receiving the following error message in the console: "VIDEOJS: ERROR: (CODE:4 MEDIA_ERR_SRC_NOT_SUPPORTED) The media could not be loaded, either because the server or network failed or because the format is not supported."

Here's my video player template code with comments:

```
<video width="640" height="300" id="videojs-vr-player" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls playsinline>
<!-- <source src="https://drive.google.com/uc?id=FILE_ID" type="video/mp4" /> -->
<!-- <source src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=FILE_ID" type="video/mp4" /> -->
<!-- <source src="https://drive.google.com/uc?id=FILE_ID&export=download" type="video/mp4" /> -->
<source src="https://drive.google.com/uc?authuser=0&id=FILE_ID&export=download" type="video/mp4" />
```

Please note that the video I'm trying to access is shared with "Anyone on the internet with the link can view" permission.

I've tried various formats of the source URL as shown in the code comments, but I still can't get it to work. Is there a way to resolve the CORS issue and ensure VideoJS can play videos shared in this manner from Google Drive?

Any help or guidance on this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: About `trying to play videos hosted on Google Drive`, how much file size is your video?

Comment: @Tanaike It varies, The current one I am trying is about 4 GB in size.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I proposed an answer. Please confirm it. If that was not useful for your situation, I apologize.

Comment: You simply can't use Google Drive for this. CORS headers have to be set by the server; they don't set them because they don't want to be acting as a CDN for your video. You need to host elsewhere. And if the file is that large, you need to think about generating multi-bitrate HLS.

Answer (score 1):

From your following

> @Tanaike It varies, The current one I am trying is about 4 GB in size.

in your situation, I guess that the reason for your current issue might be due to the file size. In the current stage, in order to download a file of a large size with `webContentLink` like `https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1{fileId}&export=download`, it is required to run the following 2 steps.

1. Retrieve the ID for downloading.
2. Download the file using the ID.

You can see it at [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48133859). I thought that this might be the reason for your current issue. In order to directly download the file to avoid this process, how about using the API key? When the API key is used, the endpoint is as follows.

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/{fileId}?alt=media&key={your API key}
```

- In this case, the file is required to be publicly shared. Please be careful about this.
- If the file is in the shared drive, please add a query parameter of `supportsAllDrives=true` like `https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/{fileId}?alt=media&key={your API key}&supportsAllDrives=true` and test it again.

#### References:

- [Authenticate by using API keys](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/api-keys)
- [Method: files.get of Drive API v3](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/reference/rest/v3/files/get)