# Authenticate or Bypass Login Downloading Google Drive File

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-drive-api, python-requests

I am trying to download a large file from my Google Drive, using the requests module solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25010369/wget-curl-large-file-from-google-drive/39225039#39225039). (It's the solution with 151 points.)

The problem I run into is that the file is not downloaded, only the response from what I think are several redirects. I end up with a 1500 line file that looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta content="width=300, initial-scale=1" name="viewport">
  <meta name="description" content="Google Drive is a free way to keep your files backed up and easy to reach from any phone, tablet, or computer. Start with 15GB of Google storage – free.">
  <meta name="google-site-verification" content="LrdTUW9psUAMbh4Ia074-BPEVmcpBxF6Gwf0MSgQXZs">
  <title>Meet Google Drive – One place for all your files</title>
  <style>
  @font-face {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 300;
  src: local('Open Sans Light'), local('OpenSans-Light'), url(//fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v15/mem5YaGs126MiZpBA-UN_r8OUuhs.ttf) format('truetype');
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Open Sans'), local('OpenSans'), url(//fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v15/mem8YaGs126MiZpBA-UFVZ0e.ttf) format('truetype');
}
  </style>
  <style>
  h1, h2 {
```

...

```
  } catch (err) {
  document.getElementById('bgresponse').value = '';
  }
  return true;
  }
  document.getElementById('gaia_loginform').onsubmit = gaia_onLoginSubmit;
  var signinButton;
  signinButton = document.getElementById('next');
  gaia_attachEvent(window, 'load', function(){
  gaia_scrollToElement(signinButton);
  });
  })();
</script>
  <script nonce="0B6waBnPr4W7otWlyB0B/g">var e=this,g=function(a,c){a=a.split(".");var b=e;a[0]in b||!b.execScript||b.execScript("var "+a[0]);for(var d;a.length&&(d=a.shift());)a.length||void 0===c?b[d]?b=b[d]:b=b[d]={}:b[d]=c};var h=function(){try{return new XMLHttpRequest}catch(b){for(var a=["MSXML2.XMLHTTP.6.0","MSXML2.XMLHTTP.3.0","MSXML2.XMLHTTP","Microsoft.XMLHTTP"],c=0;c<a.length;c++)try{return new ActiveXObject(a[c])}catch(d){}}return null};g("gaia.ajax.newXmlHttpRequest",h);var k=function(){this.a=h();this.parameters={}};g("gaia.ajax.XmlHttpFormRequest",k);
k.prototype.send=function(a,c){var b=[],d;for(d in this.parameters)b.push(d+"="+encodeURIComponent(this.parameters[d]));b=b.join("&");var f=this.a;f.open("POST",a,!0);f.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");f.onreadystatechange=function(){4==f.readyState&&c({status:f.status,text:f.responseText})};f.send(b)};k.prototype.send=k.prototype.send;
k.prototype.h=function(a,c,b){var d=this.a;d.open("POST",a,!0);d.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/json");d.onreadystatechange=function(){4==d.readyState&&b({status:d.status,text:d.responseText})};d.send(c)};k.prototype.sendJson=k.prototype.h;k.prototype.get=function(a,c){var b=this.a;b.open("GET",a,!0);b.onreadystatechange=function(){4==b.readyState&&c({status:b.status,text:b.responseText})};b.send()};k.prototype.get=k.prototype.get;var l=/\s*;\s*/,m=function(){if(!document.cookie)return"";for(var a=document.cookie.split(l),c=0;c<a.length;c++){var b=a[c];b=b.replace(/^\s+/,"");b=b.replace(/\s+$/,"");if(0==b.indexOf("APISID="))return b.substr(7)}return""};var n=null,p=function(a,c){this.g=a;this.f=c;this.c=m();this.b=!1},q=function(){var a=n,c=m();c==a.c||a.b||(a.c=c,(new k).get(a.f,function(b){var a=n;b&&b.status&&200==b.status&&"OK"==b.text&&(a.a&&clearInterval(a.a),a.b||(window.location=a.g))}))};p.prototype.start=function(a){if(this.a)return!1;this.a=setInterval(function(){q()},a);return!0};g("gaia.loginAutoRedirect.start",function(a,c,b){if(n||!b||!c||0>=a)return!1;n=new p(c,b);return n.start(a)});
g("gaia.loginAutoRedirect.stop",function(){var a=n;a.b=!0;a.a&&(clearInterval(a.a),a.a=null)});
</script>
  <script type="text/javascript" nonce="0B6waBnPr4W7otWlyB0B/g">
  gaia.loginAutoRedirect.start(5000,
  'https:\x2F\x2Faccounts.google.com\x2FServiceLogin?continue=https%3A%2F%2Fdrive.google.com%2Fuc%3Fexport%3Ddownload%26id%3D1fqA6AS0PRxZm6Pny8MW9yX24eozjFxms\x26followup=https%3A%2F%2Fdrive.google.com%2Fuc%3Fexport%3Ddownload%26id%3D1fqA6AS0PRxZm6Pny8MW9yX24eozjFxms\x26service=wise\x26ltmpl=drive\x26passive=1209600\x26noautologin=true',
  'https:\x2F\x2Faccounts.google.com\x2FPassiveLoginProber?continue=https%3A%2F%2Fdrive.google.com%2Fuc%3Fexport%3Ddownload%26id%3D1fqA6AS0PRxZm6Pny8MW9yX24eozjFxms\x26followup=https%3A%2F%2Fdrive.google.com%2Fuc%3Fexport%3Ddownload%26id%3D1fqA6AS0PRxZm6Pny8MW9yX24eozjFxms\x26service=wise\x26ltmpl=drive\x26passive=1209600');
  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I'm not sure what this means. It looks like it's trying to do something with logging in. Can someone explain what's happening and how I can download the actual file instead?

By the way...I have tried to use Google Drive's API, but due to limitations I do not have access to their Google Platform Services, so that's not an option.

Comment: Im not clear what  you said. You can write content to file and open your html file in browser. If it shows login page which means you need to do this, then continue downloading

Comment: No, the  output I provided is a snippet of the response I receive from making a request to Google Drive. It does not show me a login page.

Comment: what you are seeing is an html page. I suggest saving it as foo.html and then loading it into a browser. You'll see some kind of error message or at least a clue as to what Google thinks you are doing.

Comment: Thanks, this answered my question. I was able to open the html in a browser and then login to Google.