# SSL Error when using gdown downloading from Google Drive

Tags: python, curl, google-drive-api, wget

I want to download some large files to my server directly from Google Drive. So I learned the methods of gdown from the post here:

[wget/curl large file from google drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25010369/wget-curl-large-file-from-google-drive?answertab=votes#tab-top)

I already make sure those files are shared and **Anyone with the shareable link can view**. I copied the shareable link https://drive.google.com/open?id=1pO3NuUIkCF3-ZvUVI6JcI-BDe9gzCkX3 and changed  to .

The command I run was:

```
gdown https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1GwPudL00Im8yi-jJepPS6SKXn4sxvvT9
```

Still I get an error regarding the OPENSSL.

The detailed error log is pasted below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/yangyxt/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 472, in wrap_socket
    cnx.do_handshake()
  File "/home/yangyxt/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 1915, in do_handshake
    self._raise_ssl_error(self._ssl, result)
  File "/home/yangyxt/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 1639, in _raise_ssl_error
    raise SysCallError(errno, errorcode.get(errno))
OpenSSL.SSL.SysCallError: (104, 'ECONNRESET')

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/yangyxt/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 603, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "/home/yangyxt/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 344, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "/home/yangyxt/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 843, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "/home/yangyxt/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 370, in connect
    ssl_context=context)
  File "/home/yangyxt/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py", line 355, in ssl_wrap_socket
    return context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
  File "/home/yangyxt/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 478, in wrap_socket
    raise ssl.SSLError('bad handshake: %r' % e)
ssl.SSLError: ("bad handshake: SysCallError(104, 'ECONNRESET')",)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/yangyxt/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 449, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "/home/yangyxt/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 641, in urlopen
    _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/home/yangyxt/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 399, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='drive.google.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /uc?id=1pO3NuUIkCF3-ZvUVI6JcI-BDe9gzCkX3 (Caused by SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: SysCallError(104, 'ECONNRESET')",),))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/yangyxt/anaconda3/bin/gdown", line 10, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/home/yangyxt/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gdown/cli.py", line 100, in main
    speed=args.speed,
  File "/home/yangyxt/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gdown/download.py", line 77, in download
    res = sess.get(url, stream=True)
  File "/home/yangyxt/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 546, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "/home/yangyxt/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 533, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/home/yangyxt/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 646, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/home/yangyxt/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 514, in send
    raise SSLError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='drive.google.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /uc?id=1pO3NuUIkCF3-ZvUVI6JcI-BDe9gzCkX3 (Caused by SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: SysCallError(104, 'ECONNRESET')",),))
```