# torchvision.datasets.utils.download_file_from_google_drive downloads a zip file turns out broken

Tags: pytorch

I'm downloading a zip file from google drive using torch `download_file_from_google_drive` with corresponding file_id i'm trying:

```
download_file_from_google_drive(file_id=file_id, root=str(Path(".")), filename="filename.zip")
```

download a file which has the same size what i want to download but when i try to read it or extract it i get

```
OSError 22
```

from python or Archive is broken from b1freearchiver i don't know where the problem starts. Any help is appreciated.

```
def _extract_zip(from_path: str, to_path: str, compression: Optional[str]) -> None:
    with zipfile.Zipfile(
        from_path, "r", compression=_ZIP_COMPRESSION_MAP[compression] if compression else zipfile.ZIP_STORED) as zip:
        zip.extractall(to_path)

_extract_zip(str(Path(".") / "filename.zip"), str(Path("."))
```

Comment: How are you extracting the file ? If you are using python add that code to your description.

Comment: Used updated version: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25010369/wget-curl-large-file-from-google-drive/39225039#39225039](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25010369/wget-curl-large-file-from-google-drive/39225039#39225039)

Comment: Could you add the entire error stack ?

Comment: it worked using the linked function above