# How to download large .tgz file from Google drive for installing Docker containers on Cloud9 Ubuntu 18.04LTS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloud9

This is the Google drive file -
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HIDg5ksQCY7Hd37AaxXlv32vLVzyrkpw/view

32G = EBS volume of Cloud9 cluster

Cloud9 EC2 Instance Type = t3.medium (4 GiB RAM + 2 vCPU)

NOTE:
curl -L or wget commands are not working.
Installed and used `gdown` with below error -

```
ubuntu:~/environment $ gdown https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HIDg5ksQCY7Hd37AaxXlv32vLVzyrkpw/
/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gdown/parse_url.py:48: UserWarning: You specified a Google Drive link that is not the correct link to download a file. You might want to try `--fuzzy` option or the following url: https://drive.google.com/uc?id=None
  url="https://drive.google.com/uc?id={}".format(file_id)
Downloading...
From: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HIDg5ksQCY7Hd37AaxXlv32vLVzyrkpw/
To: /home/ubuntu/environment
75.9kB [00:00, 353MB/s]
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: ''
```

The curl -L command error is as follows -

```
ubuntu:~/environment $ curl -L https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HIDg5ksQCY7Hd37AaxXlv32vLVzyrkpw/view?usp=sharing
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><meta name="google" content="notranslate"><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge;">
```

// Google Inc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to SO answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/50670037/786676

Steps followed -

Download and install grown `pip install gdown`

Copy the file-id `1HIDg5ksQCY7Hd37AaxXlv32vLVzyrkpw`

Run command `gdown file-id`

ubuntu:~/environment $ gdown 1HIDg5ksQCY7Hd37AaxXlv32vLVzyrkpw
Downloading...
From (uriginal): https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1HIDg5ksQCY7Hd37AaxXlv32vLVzyrkpw
From (redirected): https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1HIDg5ksQCY7Hd37AaxXlv32vLVzyrkpw&confirm=t&uuid=969d7bf0-b65d-4eeb-b469-e37bf5b031d0
To: /home/ubuntu/environment/bigdata.tgz
100%|██████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 3.31G/3.31G [00:26<00:00, 127MB/s]