# Cant access getWebContentLink() property of a file in service account google drive using java

Tags: java, google-drive-api

I have created a service account in google drive for uploading files in google drive from server and download those files later. But when I tried to get list of files of a folder and get the `webContentLinks` of those file, it returned null. I checked it for some other properties, it returns null for both `getWebContentLink()` and `getWebViewLink()` except the file name and file id.

Can anyone help me to get the `webContentLink` or can you figure out the issue about why I cant get `webContentLink`.

Here is a part of code I tried:

```
  List<String> linkList=new ArrayList<String>();
  fileFlag=0;
  pageToken = null;
  do {
      driveFiles = service.files().list()
              .setQ("mimeType!='application/vnd.google-apps.folder and "+childFolder.getId()+"' in parents ")
              .setSpaces("drive")
              .setFields("nextPageToken, files(id, name)")
              .setPageToken(pageToken)
              .execute();
      System.out.println("\n\nFile No. : "+driveFiles.getFiles().size());
      for(com.google.api.services.drive.model.File file: driveFiles.getFiles()) {
         linkList.add(file.getWebContentLink());
         System.out.println(file.getName());
         System.out.println("File Link : "+file.getWebContentLink());
         System.out.println(file.getId());
         System.out.println(file.getWebViewLink());
      }
      pageToken = driveFiles.getNextPageToken();
  } while (pageToken != null);
```

Here is one of the Output

```
File No. : 4
V2__data.sql
File Link : null
0BzCRyzakN8eJOGRTODhXTFkxUWc
null
V1__table.sql
File Link : null
0BzCRyzakN8eJT09BbG5JUFdNYmc
null
V2__data.sql
File Link : null
0BzCRyzakN8eJa0FyUGw3UFZJZ00
null
V1__table.sql
File Link : null
0BzCRyzakN8eJcDJNWHY4cFNHMW8
null
```

Comment: I think you have the same issue with [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20665881/direct-download-from-google-drive-using-google-drive-api). Check it out, might help.

Comment: I have already checked that thread. But webContentLink is not even working for small files. Since that method will be disabled after August 16, I cant use that. The value of webContentLink is null. That is my main issue. @noogui

Comment: Service Account don't have a web API, so it's possible that this is why there is no webcontentUrl. What are you trying to do? Try looking for a downloadUrl or expoertLinks.

Comment: I am looking for downloadUrl. @pinoyyid

Comment: I've read in this [Google Drive Rest Doc](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-downloads#downloading_google_documents) that "If you want to allow an unauthorized user to view a file directly in a web browser instead of through the API, use the webContentLink. You can either redirect a user to this URL, or offer it as a clickable link."

Try specifying the weblink in the medata data like "webViewLink": string, as stated [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files#resource-representations).

Comment: @noogui That does not apply to Service Accounts.

Comment: @For_A_While you're calling "setFields(files(id, name)", so you're telling drive to only return the id and name properties. Therefore all other properties will be null.

Comment: You are right. Thanks for the help. XD.@pinoyyid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As commented by @pinoyyid, adding webContentLink in the setFields property of the drive query solved the problem.

```
  List<String> linkList=new ArrayList<String>();
  fileFlag=0;
  pageToken = null;
  do {
      driveFiles = service.files().list()
              .setQ("mimeType!='application/vnd.google-apps.folder' and '"+childFolder.getId()+"' in parents ")
              .setSpaces("drive")
              .setFields("nextPageToken, files(id, name, webContentLink)")
              .setPageToken(pageToken)
              .execute();
      System.out.println("\n\nFile No. : "+driveFiles.getFiles().size());
      for(com.google.api.services.drive.model.File file: driveFiles.getFiles()) {
         linkList.add(file.getWebContentLink());
         System.out.println(file.getName());
         System.out.println("File Link : "+file.getWebContentLink());
         System.out.println(file.getId());
         System.out.println(file.getWebViewLink());
      }
      pageToken = driveFiles.getNextPageToken();
  } while (pageToken != null);
```

Comment: This was very useful, thanks. Is there a way to get a public webContentLink? like if I add a token or something?

Comment: @casolorz The file can be downloaded through webContentLink without any authentication from any browser.

Comment: some of the files I'm trying to do this with aren't public, will that work for them?