# Fetch file from Google drive with GNU Octave

Tags: octave, fetch

Here's a link to a shared file:

`https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B84DlMErV9QYSFVYbEluMXQ4VlE`

How can the rar file behind be fetched and stored locally with GNU Octave commands?  `urlwrite()` would not make it, as it downloads an html file. ftp connections are not allowed in Google drive.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Google Drive Direct Link Generator](https://sites.google.com/site/gdocs2direct/) and then urlwrite:

```
urlwrite ("https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0B84DlMErV9QYSFVYbEluMXQ4VlE", "foobar.rar")
```

Or use `regexprep` to change the URL (the format should be obvious)

See also [SO question howto use google drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20665881/direct-download-from-google-drive-using-google-drive-api) because this is question is mostly howto get a direct link and not really Octave related.

Comment: Following the instructions you provide, the link I get is of a different kind: `https://docs.google.com/document/d/1uKPq50DwwK3yaEY9l2btqV457bLGM3R8HQJO2jYgI4g/edit?usp=sharing`, and `urlwrite` does write an html file, not the original rar file.

Comment: If I enter https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B84DlMErV9QYSFVYbEluMXQ4VlE/view I get https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0B84DlMErV9QYSFVYbEluMXQ4VlE perhaps you've missed the /view ?

Comment: Gosh, how do you get that url? If I enter it in the browser it simply opens up the Google drive site with the test.txt file in it. When I press the download button, it shows for a brief time the address  `https://docs.google.com/uc?id=0B84DlMErV9QYSFVYbEluMXQ4VlE&export=download`, which I believe it's equivalent to yours, cause then `urlwrite` does work, but how to obtain it without pressing on download and been quick enough (before the window collapses and the download of the file starts) ?

Comment: Are you trolling me?

Comment: ??  nope, this is just what it happens, don't know how do you get that address, it is not what I get. And, without that address, the original file is not fetched.