# Download Google doc file to device

Tags: android, google-drive-android-api

I am trying to download a doc.google file to my device, however I can't figure the best way for that..

First: I created an Auth key to my Drive following this [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/auth)

Then: I am trying to follow this [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-downloads#downloading_google_documents) to download the file, but It is not going well

I want to connect to this Auth key through the app and download/Export the file automatically without prompting the user to choose account or anything..

This is the URL for the doc file:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QJTna4iz-VivwAzwgq7V5QDs2XbgM2lEFPEG7NqCPdo/

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try the method used in this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21390469).

It was cited that to overcome the google problem when setting the file publicly. As in the post:

> If you set the file permissions to be publicly available and
>   create/generate a direct access link by using something like the
>   [gdocs2direct](https://sites.google.com/site/gdocs2direct/) tool or just crafting the link yourself:
>
> ```
> https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&id=<your file id>
> ```
>
> You will get a cookie based verification code and prompt "Google could
>   not scan this file" prompt, which won't work for things such as
>   **wget** or Vagrantfile configs.
>
> The code that it generates is a simple code that appends GET query
>   variable `...&confirm=###` to the string, but it's per user specific,
>   so it's not like you can copy/paste that query variable for others.

The specified web page hosting method will suffice.